# How to make search in MySQL when using CASE-WHEN-THEN in SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, filter, case-when

I have a situation where we are calculating the payment status for a project.

The "CASE" clause is used to find the payment status

Now I need to make a filter in the SQL on the result which came out from the calculations of CASE-statement for example if "Paid" is selected in the filter than we need to see only those records whose payment status is "Paid".

I know that we can not use alias in the WHERE clause.

In my case I have added an aliase with name "pm_clause" in the WHERE clause but added in the following SQL for reference.

Is there a way to apply such filters in the SQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT rs.id AS rs_id
, SUM(rs.amount_payable) AS revenue
, SUM(rs.amount_recieved) AS receipt
, GROUP_CONCAT(rs.payment_status) AS payment_status
, s.id AS s_id
, s.file_number
, s.company_id
, s.travel_start_date
, s.travel_region
, s.country
, s.lead_name
, c.id
, c.name AS company
, c.currency_sign
, c.currency_code
, CASE WHEN SUM(rs.amount_recieved) = SUM(rs.amount_payable) 
     THEN "Paid"
     WHEN SUM(rs.amount_recieved) = 0 
     THEN "Not Paid"
     WHEN SUM(rs.amount_recieved) > 0 AND SUM(rs.amount_recieved) < SUM(rs.amount_payable) 
     THEN "Part paid"
     WHEN SUM(rs.amount_recieved) > SUM(rs.amount_payable) 
      THEN "Overpaid"
      ELSE "Error" END AS pm_status   
  FROM  erp_revenue_schedule rs
  JOIN erp_sales s
      ON s.id = rs.sales_id
  JOIN erp_company c
      ON c.id = s.company_id  
WHERE  rs.is_active = 1 
   AND s.is_active = 1 
   AND c.is_active = 1  
   AND pm_status = 'Not paid'  
 ORDER 
    BY rs.id   asc  
 LIMIT 0 ,10
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

When you have normal columns and aggregate functions in select, you need to use `GROUP BY`, not `DISTINCT`.

Also, it is unclear why you need the `CASE` statement at all, if you only want rows that have `SUM(rs.amount_recieved) = 0`. A condition with aggregate function goes into `HAVING`-clause, not in `WHERE`.

Comment: Thank you Slaako for your response. 

Actually there are multiple cases e.g. Paid, Not Paid, Part Paid and Overpaid.

So, all these filters can be checked on the basis of cases which I mentioned in the SQL.

I want to have option for all filters not only the case of "Not Paid".

Basically we are using a DataTable and implemented a custom filter using the HTML dropdown form. So, we pass the value of dropdown in the API call to get the filtered data.

Getting all data in first time page load is fine, but when a filter is select I definately need to load data on the basis of that param.

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY` statement to the query and move the aggregate condition to a `HAVING`-clause. The combination of `rs.id` and `SUM(rs.amount_payable)` looks incorrect if `id` is the primary key for the `erp_revenue_schedule` table.